# If $(\frac{Q}{P})=1$, then the congruence above doesn't have a solution.

Tags: number-theory

Let P and Q be integers such that P is odd, and gcd(P,Q)=1. Consider the congruence equation $X^2 \equiv Q \pmod P$. What is an example that shows that

If $(\frac{Q}{P})=1$, then the congruence above doesn't have a solution.

Comment: What is the meaning of $(\frac{Q}{P})=1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $P=15$ and $Q=17$. Note that the **Legendre** symbols $(17/3)$ and $(17/5)$ are both $-1$. So the **Jacobi** symbol $(Q/P)$ is equal to $1$. But the congruence $X^2\equiv 17\pmod{15}$ does not have a solution. For if it did, the congruence $X^2\equiv 17\pmod{3}$ would have a solution. But it doesn't.

We conclude that if a Jacobi symbol $(Q/P)$ is equal to $1$, it is *not necessarily* the case that the congruence $X^2\equiv Q\pmod{P}$ has a solution. Of course there are always *some* $Q$ such that $(Q/P)=1$ and the congruence $X^2\equiv Q\pmod{P}$ has a solution. Take for example $Q=1$.